# Need to generate same serialized value in java similar to CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement Windows API

Tags: java, c++, windows, serialization, certificate

I want to generate the same serialized value of a certificate in Java, which is equivalent to that which is generated using CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement Windows API.

I tried generating the Serialized value of the Certificate in Java and the output generated is different.

Link to Windows API : [CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376569(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement` is a very Win32-specific notion.  The Windows Certificate Store API supports adding all sorts of metadata to a certificate which isn't part of the certificate itself (the most popular one: the location of an associated private key), and `CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement` exports the certificate along with all the properties to be able to be imported again (as a backup/restore, or export/import).

If you really need that function, you can call it on Windows via [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

If what you want is the X.509 certificate data, in Windows that's available directly on the [PCERT_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `pbCertEncoded`/`cbCertEncoded` fields.

Comment: Thank you bartonjs.

Comment: @Aravind On StackOverflow the etiquette is to mark the most correct (correct) answer to a question that you asked as correct; and to upvote any answers that are helpful; generally instead of a "thank you" comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, relatively new to ask questions here. Thank you for letting me know. I tried Upvoted but due to some issue, i wasn't able to do so.